# Building an http server

Tags: python, http, server, client, packet

So I need to build an HTTP server that will contact a client and send him data like pictures or calculations and create a page with those things. I guess you understood that I do not really know what I'm doing... :(

I know python and the basic(+) of the client-server project but I don't understand that HTTP protocol and didn't understand anything from what I read on the internet...

Can anyone explain to me how to work with this protocol? What is the form of HTTP packets?

Here an example of 1 problem that I don't understand: I have been asked to get a packet (which I did) and understand what is the request there, then send back the name of the file the client wants and after it the file itself. I printed the packet and didn't understand where is the request or what the client wants...

Thank you very very much!

Comment: Please repeat the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials, nor to provide individual tutelage.  Also see [help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain to me how to work with this protocol? What is the form of HTTP packets?

[The specification might be helpful.](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

Concerning the webz, you find a lot of specification on the RFCs.
More to HTTP below.

---

(Since you seem to be new to programming, I figured I might want to tell you the following:)

Usually one doesn't directly interact with HTTP(S) packets. Instead you use a framework, such as [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/), [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) and many more. The choice of framework depends on the use-case. E.g.:

- You need a database, authentication and any imaginable feature? Go with Django.
- You just want to create a WebApplication without a bloated framework? Go with Flask.
- You need the bare minimum or want to act as a client? Go with aiohttp.

More frameworks are listed [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks).

The advantage of using such frameworks is that they usually include useful things, that are battletested (i.e. usually no bugs), while you don't have to figure out pecularities of certain protocols.

You just import the framework and write awesomeness! :)

---

(Anyways, here is a little very oversimplified overview for completeness)

So, HTTP is an text protocol over TCP, which basically means that you send text over a simple tcp [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html). When you receive your request you have to "parse" (i.e. comprehend its contents). Luckily for us the requests are standarized and follow the same scheme.

The smallest request would look like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.server.com
```

The first line starts with a [verb (also called request method)](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), in our example the verb is `GET`. The `/` denotes the path. Think of file paths on your HDD. The last part of the first line, namely `HTTP/1.0`, tells the receiver with which version of HTTP we are operating on. Currently the there is HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1; however, I wouldn't bother with HTTP 1.1 yet and stick with HTTP 1.0, if you're implementing the requests your self.

Lastly the `Host: www.server.com` line tells us which server we want to talk to, since multiple instances of an HTTP server could be running under the same ip. This is used to revole the subdomain.

If you send this request to an HTTP Server, you're likely to receive an response like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: Apache/1.3.29 (Unix) PHP/4.3.4
Content-Length: 1337
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<DATA>
```

This response contains the status in the first line `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`. The number and the 'OK' represent a status code, telling us that everything is fine. There are [many status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) with their own meaning and usages.

The lines following the first are so-called Response-Headers. They provide additional useful information about the response. For instance, when we open a site like 'stackoverflow.com', the server transmits an HTML file to us for the browser to interpret. Before we can do that, we need to know the size of the HTML file.

Luckily the server tells us beforehand with `Content-Length: 1337` line, that the file is 1337 bytes big. The file itself would be present where the `<DATA>` placeholder stands.

There are, yet again, many of these [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

---

As you can see, there are many things to account for when working with HTTP, showing that it is not feasible, without a very good reason, to implement a HTTP client/server from scratch.

Instead it's preferred to use one of the frameworks (for python) listed above.

---

As a last note:
In the process of trying to explain the concepts as simple as possible I probably left-out or oversimplified some things. If you find any mistake, please let me know.

Comment: First of all thank you so much! You really helped me!
About the frameworks Its a work I have to do in python without frameworks but It's nice to know about this :)
I will continue my question in the next comment (too many characters)

Comment: This is a packet: `GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7`

Comment: I can't find here the request the client sends me... Can you explain it to me?